# What's the best way to Integrate a composition of multiple functions

Tags: integration, derivatives

The functions are totally different.
For example;
Integrate: $f(x)=\arctan(\ln(x^\frac{1}{(2x+e)})$
Uhmm.. Yeah kind of something like that.
How the hell do I do it

Comment: There is no best way. Integration is art, fantasy and intuition. Try, wonder, do.

Comment: This got an upvote??

Comment: First you need to realize that this is NOT "a product of multiple functions"!  It is, rather, a **composition** of functions.  Typically the way you integrate compositions of functions is by "substitution".  **However** in integration that requires that the derivative of the substituted term already be in the integral.  The function you give here, like **most** functions, *cannot* be integrated in simple form.

Comment: @user247327 Oh shoot, yeah it is a composition, I was thinking of a product then remembered that cursed one... My bad.

Comment: Most of the times you can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others already pointed out, it's not always possibile. This is because integration is, as I said, a form of art.

What you need to solve an integral, you may not need in solving another one.
Be it an integral of composite functions, more composite functions, nested composite functions et cetera. The fact is that when you write a composition of functions, the resulting function can be either simple or hard.

**Trivial Example**

Take $f(x) = 1/x$ and $g(x) = \ln(x)$.

$$f \circ g = \frac{1}{\ln(x)}$$

$$g \circ f = \ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

The second one has a trivial integral.

The first one does not, and indeed is classified as a Special Function, the Logarithm Integral. Values are tabulated but you won't find an analytical primitive.

In your example, after some easy manipulation, you end up with the fancy but painful integral

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \arctan\left(z \frac{\ln(z) - \ln(2)}{z^2 + \ln(2)\ln(z)}\right)\ \text{d}x$$

Which has no close analytical form.

Unless of course you want an approximation for example in the case of very small $z$ or whatever.

General methods are rare, and they apply even more rarely.